# C++builder AES LockBox with bytes array

Tags: aes, c++builder, lockbox-3

I would like to encrypt in `AES`, some binary data using `LockBox 3.5.0 library` in `C++Builder 10`.

I have key and binary data placed in bytes arrays.

> key(hex): E8 E9 EA EB ED EE EF F0 F2 F3 F4 F5 F7 F8 F9 FA
>
> plain data(hex): 01 4B AF 22 78 A6 9D 33 1D 51 80 10 36 43 E9 9A

Also chipher data needs to be placed in bytes array.

I've found some examples with string encoding, but have no idea how do this with the binary data.

Can I use `EncryptMemory` or `EncryptStream` for this ?

Any examples will be appreciated ,thanks.